# How to execute Netbeans (built from source) from jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build

I´ve just build Netbeans from source code following the steps posted here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/WorkingWithNetBeansSources
It also says that is posible to run it with ant from command line, but I need to run it from a jar File. 
Anyone knows how can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "a jar file"? Is it your application?

Comment: I mean that, like in other applications which I can download the source code and, after build it, I have a launcher of the application which is a jar file, and I want to do the same with NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Use `build-zip-ml` target.

```
cd nbbuild
ant build-zip-ml
```